# Pulling info from SQL Server with Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am tasked with pulling information from SAP and cross referencing it to information pulled from Active Directory. The first step I need to obviously accomplish would be to figure out how to pull certain information out of the SQL Server. Here is what I have so far (thanks to several users here who have answered somewhat similar questions):

```
$SQLServer = "WEB-PRDSQ"
$SQLDBName = "PRD"
$SqlQuery = "SELECT * from prd.ZEMPLOYEE;"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; User ID = DELETED; Password = DELETED;"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)

$DataSet.Tables[0] | out-file "C:\Scripts\SQL\SQLData.csv"
```

And this is the output it gives me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqOx3.png

For one, this is an ugly layout that is hard to read when there are 145,361 lines of text. And 2, I don't need all this information. All I need is their sAMAccountName (I don't see this as one of the output, but that's what it's called in AD), Emp_ID, Status, Hire_Date, Location, Emp_Title, LastLogonDate (once again, don't see this as an output but I know it's in AD), and lastly Term_Date.

When I try to change the "SELECT * from prd.ZEMPLOYEE" and change out the * for Status, Hire_Date, etc, it gives the error "Invalid column name 'Status'" (or whatever column I have listed first).

Is there someone out there who is patient enough to help work me through this and help me create this? I've only taken one Database class so I kinda know what I am talking about, but also don't know the intricate details that this may require. I am willing to help provide any information I need to.

Comment: Having extracted a good deal of data from SAP in the past, are your BASIS admins okay with you directly connecting to what appears as your production database?

Comment: I would assume so, my CIO is the one who is telling me what he wants done, so he knows exactly what I am connecting to.

Comment: I'm not sure what your database Collation is set to, but you might try the column names in your `SELECT` statement in all caps.  If the database is a case sensitive Collation, you would match the output you received.

Comment: You are correct, I didn't realize it would be case sensitive. Thank you very much for your help. However, do you know if/how I would be able to get sAMAccountName and LastLogonDate to show on the output as well?

Comment: Is that all you needed?

Comment: I was also wondering how I would have sAMAccountName and LastLogonDate appear on the output file like they would in AD. This may not be possible since both of those aren't columns for the table, but if it is possible I need that as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83794/discussion-between-jradich1234-and-mason-evans).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per earlier conversation...

Database Collation is case sensitive and column names must match the same case shown in the results file from the `Select * From...` query.

Example:
`Select EMP_ID, STATUS From prd.ZEMPLOYEE`